# End program through a function?

Tags: c++

Sorry for such a beginner question, but is there a way to end a program through a function outside of main? I was wanting to end the program based on the user input. If user cin 'no' I wanted the program to terminate.

```
char askStart(string question)
{       
    char response;

    do {

        cout << question << "(y/n): ";
        cin >> response;

    } while (response != 'y' && response != 'n');

    { 
        if (response == 'n') {

            cout << "\nVery well then....\n\n";

        } else {

            cout << "\nHere we go!\n\n";

        }

       return response; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is `exit`.

Comment: @self Actually, since it's a do-while, your code is correct. I think Cyber thought it was a regular while-loop? The curly brace after the while is confusing since it's extraneous, and the incorrect indentation doesn't help :p You're not inside the while there btw.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I only glanced briefly, it is a do-while loop, not a while loop, that is correct

Comment: Introducing new scope for an `if` statement?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I am fixing it now lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can end a program at any point by calling `std::exit`:

```
#include <cstdlib>

void foo()
{
    std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

In fact, the behaviour of returning a value `n` from `main` is identical to calling `std::exit(n);`.

Note that `exit` ends all running threads, and if you haven't explicitly joined them, you may incur various kinds of undefined or undesirable behaviour.